# How to pass multiple input values from HTML to a SObject created in LWC

Tags: sobject

I have over 100 input field values in HTML that will be passed to a SObject created in the LWC JS. The SObject will be passed to the server side to persist data.

Every time there is a new input field value, I would have to create a onChange, a function to store value to a variable then pass it to the SObject. Is there a better to do this?

Example for 1 input field:

HTML

```
<lightning-input 
    type="text"
    label="Notes"
    value={note}
    onchange={handle_note} > 
</lightning-input>
```

JS

```
@api note;

handle_note(event) {
    this.note = event.detail.value;
}
    
handle_Submit(event){
        let cust = {
            sobjectType: "Cust__c"
          };
cust.note = this.note
... // Pass sobject to the server side to persist data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript allows use to access fields dynamically, using array notation, so we write our handler as:

```
handleChange (event) {
  this.record[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
}
```

Then we just set the name:

```
<lightning-input 
  type="text"
  label="Notes"
  name="Note__c"
  value={note}
  onchange={handleChange} > 
</lightning-input>
```

From here, you can actually just set the handler on a common parent element:

```
<div onchange={handleChange}>
  Put your input elements here...
</div>
```

Comment: So I should set the handler on a common parent instead of having one inside each input field? Because every event.target.value will be stored to their their name field accordingly

Comment: @ApexCowboy I wrote an [example](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/DFWv9vqC7zOtyhq02PCd/src/app.html?p=stories) where we use dynamic form rendering for you. It really can be this simple.

Comment: Thanks your solution works great. --- I might open a new question for this later: I successfully passed all data to SObject this.note which is declared globally, but the handleSubmit that passes it to the backend for storing doesn't seem to recognize it in the function.

Comment: All is good! Fixed minor issue, cheers